# Frequency distribution with custom format data

Tags: r

I need help with a R plot, with a data format I have not worked with before. Please help if you know.

```
NUMBER   FREQUENCY
10          1  
11          1  
12          3  
10          45   
11          2  
12          3
```

i need a bar plot with numbers on X axis (continuous, not bins in histogram) and frequency on Y, but combined.
like

```
10     46  
11     3  
12     6
```

it seems simple enough, but i have 10,000 rows and large numbers in real data so I am looking for a good solution in R without doing it manually.

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
##tapply splits dd$FREQ by dd$NUM and "sums" them
barplot(tapply(dd$FREQUENCY, dd$NUMBER, sum))
```

to get:

[image]

---

Read in your data:

```
dd = read.table(textConnection("NUMBER   FREQUENCY
10          1  
11          1  
12          3  
10          45   
11          2  
12          3"), header=TRUE)
```